# Problem with the Interaction Representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Consider a Hamiltonian $H(t) = H_0 +V(t)$. Let $\hat{\psi}=e^{iH_0 t} \psi$ be the state in the interaction picture where $\psi$ is that in the Schrodinger picture, i.e., $i\psi'=H(t)\psi$. Then we know that (formally)
$$
\hat{\psi}(t)=S(t)\psi_0
$$
where
$$
S(t)=T \exp\left( -i\int_0^t\hat{V}\right), \quad \hat{V}=e^{iH_0 t}Ve^{-iH_0 t}
$$
However, this seems to lead to a paradox. More specifically, consider the case where the interaction $V$ is time-independent, i.e.., $V(t) =V$ so that $H(t)=H$ would also be time independent. Then we see that $\psi =e^{-iHt} \psi_0$ and that $S(t) = e^{-i\hat{V}t}$. Hence,
\begin{align}
e^{-i\hat{V}t} \psi_0 &= e^{iH_0 t} e^{-iHt}\psi_0 \\
e^{-iVt} &= e^{-iHt} e^{iH_0 t}\\
\end{align}
Now obviously, this equality cannot hold in general by the BCH equality, so what is wrong? The most obvious justification would be that the interaction picture requires that $V(t)$ disappear at $t\to \pm \infty$, but I feel that this is rather weak since the argument (at least formally) does not rely upon this fact.

**To sum up**, is the interaction picture rigorous in any sense? If so, please provide a reference for such proof. If not, why is it a good approximation considering the above-mentioned paradox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because $V$ is $t$-independent doesn't mean $\hat{V}$ is. We know that $\hat{V}(t)=e^{-iH_0 t}Ve^{iH_0t}$. Therefore, you cannot generally write $S(t)=e^{i\hat V t}$, but must use the time-ordered exponential. The only time you can use the non-time-ordered exponential is when $[V,H]=0$, in which case your "paradox" disappears.

(Also: The interaction picture is an exact identity, and does not require any level of approximation)

Comment: Your answer is better than mine... +1.